# I will run 'php artisan serve', it gets started, accepted and eventually closing. why? Please

Tags: php, laravel

I have my xammp  (PHP v8.0.1), installed Laravel v8.28.1 installed composer and then created my laravel project. I will run 'php artisan serve', it gets started and each time i copy and run the ip on the browser, i get referred to Laravel home page with documentation and all that while it then gets accepted and closing like the attached image. Idon't know if am doing something right, am a newbie on the framework. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using MINGW when XAMPP runs quite happily in Windows. Or if you specifically want to use Linux, you could be using WSL

Comment: I have the same after upgrade to 7.4, i think it's a normal behavior

Comment: you can try with another port, like port 9000 `php artisan server --port=9000`

Comment: Thank you for your responses, i am still encountering the same thing even after i had changed my port to 9000, @RiggsFolly how do you mean XAMPP runs quite happily o windows. It's actually Laravel i want to work with. could you explain in details?

Comment: Lastly, may i  know the usual response when the ipp address is being run on the browser?

Comment: XAMPP has a WAMP stack option i.e. Windows Apache, Windows PHP, Windows MySQL.....

Answer (score 0):

Log message `Closing` means ending of any HTTP request/response. It is ok.

If you don't see anything in your browser try to change host to 0.0.0.0:

```sh
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I tried it didn't fix, even after i turned off my firewall. Yes, closing ends HTTP response because i noticed my CLI also stopped imputing commands.